# Is there a way to add a column to a geopandas dataframe using a single value geoseries?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I am trying to add a column to a geodataframe in Geopandas (0.4.0) with a single values (point) from a geoseries to be used in further calculations.

However, after simply creating a new column and assigning directly the geoseries, I noticed that the new column is filled with NaN.

If I use the shapely object itself I receive the following error message:
'AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape'

example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

# create some geometry
coordinates = {'lng': [1,2,3], 'lat': [4,5,6], 'loc': ['a', 'b', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(coordinates, columns = ['loc', 'lat', 'lng'])


df['geometry'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: Point((x.lat, x.lng)), 
    axis = 1)

# create point of interest
coordinates_center = {'lng': 2.2, 'lat': 4.8, 'loc': ['c']}
df_center = pd.DataFrame(coordinates_center)

df_center['geometry'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: Point((x.lat, x.lng)), 
    axis = 1)

# check data type
print (type(df_center))
center = df_center['geometry']
print (type(center))
center_point = center[0]
print (type(center_point))

#create new column in main dataframe and assign the point of interest
df.assign(center=center_point)
```

Comment: `gdf = gdf.assign(new_column=new_value)`

Comment: Hi, txs for the help. Still get just nan in the new_column. The value I am trying to assign is a shapely point

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code example? It is hard to debug something we can't see.

Comment: added the code, apologies

Answer (score 6):

The magic sauce with (geo)pandas is that it automatically aligns data on the index. So it's aligning your single value series with the index of the data frame. At most there could be only one match. If you want to assign a constant value to your new column, use a scalar.

Take for instance (and not the reproducible example I've provided):

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': [3, 4, 5]}, index=list('abc'))
s = pandas.Series([6], index=[0])

print(df.assign(C=s))
```

We get:

```
   A  B   C
a  0  3 NaN
b  1  4 NaN
c  2  5 NaN
```

This is because the index of `s` and the index of `df` have no matches. If there was a single match (since `len(s) == 1`), you'd get:

```py
s = pandas.Series([6], index=['b'])

print(df.assign(C=s))
```

```
   A  B   C
a  0  3 NaN
b  1  4 6.0
c  2  5 NaN
```

But this isn't what you want, so you should just use a scalar:

```py
print(df.assign(C=6))
```

```
   A  B  C
a  0  3  6
b  1  4  6
c  2  5  6
```

Comment: txs a lot, makes a lot of sense. in my case my scalar is a shapely object point. when trying to do what you suggest I get the assertion error I mentioned before.

Comment: @FabioL. you said you were using a series, so which is it? A scalar or a series?

Comment: it is a geoseries from the geometry column of a geodataframe containing only one value (POINT).

Comment: @FabioL. so then it's not a scalar, it's a series. Since it's a series, pandas will try to align the series with your dataframe based on the index. To get a scalar from your N = 1 series, use: `scalar = geoser.iloc[0]`

Comment: Hi Paul, I understand this. however I still receive this assertion error when trying to extract the value from the series as you suggested  and assigning to the new column in the geodataframe.

Comment: @FabioL. it's pointless to keep vaguely describing errors without an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added an exampe above. Txs F.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on shapefiles with geopandas:

```python
import geopandas as gpd


gdf = gpd.read_file(input_shp)
if 'field_name' not in gdf.columns:  # check if field exists
    gdf['field_name'] = None  # initialize field, float, two decimals
    gdf['field_name'] = gdf['field_name'].astype('float64')
    gdf['field_name'] = gdf['field_name'].round(decimals=2)

# then you can acces it in iterrows
for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    gdf.at[index, 'field_name'] = 0  # assign new value to new field

# if you want to save it
gdf.to_file('path')
```

or with apply()

```python
def modify_row(row):
    row['field_name'] = 0
    return row


modified_gdf = gdf.apply(lambda row: modify_row(row))
modified_gdf.to_file('path')
```